# How to render multiple skinned meshes in single draw calls? (Three Js)

Tags: javascript, three.js, react-three-fiber, threejs-editor

I am using same model with skeleton animation multiple times in my scene and generally when you use multiple meshes with same geometry and material, you use instancedMesh in three js to reduce the draw calls but it's not possible to do with skinned mesh. So how can render skinned meshes in single draw calls? Is there a way?

Comment: I am wondering the same thing because I need something that is an instanced mesh, but I need an instanced skinned mesh so that I can animate it. I am not sure if animating it which has so many different poses is what causes it to be impossible to do a single draw call or not.

Comment: I have since learned to use a community-created class called InstancedSkinnedMesh which inherits from SkinnedMesh and adds instanced attributes that enable it to be an instanced type.